# Joining three views into one and then using FOR XML RAW

Tags: sql, xml, view, sql-server-2000

I am trying to join 3 views like this and then output XML,

```
view4 equal (SELECT     *
FROM         view1
Join  
SELECT     *
FROM         view2
Join 
SELECT     *
FROM         view3)

 FOR XML RAW;
```

anything wrong with this query sir ? as it says wrong syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not understanding the meaning of some of your code, but this is an example of legal syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM view1
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM view2
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM view3
FOR XML RAW;
```

Note that each query should return the same number of columns and same datatypes.

`UNION` is an implicitly distinct operation as well.  `UNION ALL` would return all rows from each query.

Here is an example of how you might get different tables/views into your unioned view:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM view1 -- Has all the columns
UNION 
SELECT ColA, ColB, cast(ColC as varchar(50))
FROM view2 -- ColC is an int but other views have varchar(50)
UNION 
SELECT ColA, null, ColC
FROM view3 -- Has no ColB
```

And return XML in this fashion:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM myView
FOR XML RAW;
```

Proper [join](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) syntax might look like the following:

```
SELECT a.ColA, b.ColB, c.ColC
FROM view1 AS a
    JOIN view2 AS b ON a.SomeID = b.SomeID
    JOIN view3 AS c ON b.SomeOtherID = c.SomeOtherID
```

You can create a view and query it as XML just like the union example.

Comment: I want to combine 3 views into 1 view Sir, thanks I give it a go

Comment: +1 sir, but each view have only few common columns with same data type sir :(

Comment: You would need to cast/convert them into the same datatype, and return the same number of columns in each query. You could add a null as a column to a query if that column didn't exist.

Comment: oh, I think best idea will be to create a new view with all the information then, Sir

Comment: Sorry I wanted to Join, not Union, sorry for confusion

Comment: @user13814 Please see the join example, and visit [the link I've provided](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) for more info on joins.